# FLASK : 404 Not Found

Tags: python, flask, postman, http-post

I am trying to post data to flask API through postman as below:

```
from flask import Flask, request  


app = Flask(__name__)

 
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hi, World!</p>"

@app.route("/data", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    name = request.form.get('Name')
    if len(name) != 0:
        '<p>Data added Successfully</p>'
    else:
        '<p>Error</p>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Sending request through Postman like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXIpV.png)

But I am getting error as shown in image, can anyone please help me - I am very new to flask

When I am running the above code, I thought it will post the data in server but it is throwing error, Can anyone please help me!

When i am requesting '/' - Its working , but for '/data' its not working( Please check below image):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3S3v.png)

Comment: 404 means your api doesn't setup, maybe you can show your code more.

Comment: @JunXiang I have updated my whole code please check

Comment: If your sending request for route - "/", can it get "Hi, World" ?

Comment: I think the problem happen in `name = request.form.get('Name')`, 
I've remove the code in  login function, and just return `<p>Hi</p>`, 
it can request successfully.

Comment: @JunXiang I want to post data to server, How can i do that? If you know can you please guide me

Comment: you are getting `404` error as `http://127.0.0.1:5000/data` post method is not recognized, is there a chance that this code is not saved and flask did not start back again even though you have set up `debug=True`? pls save code and restart the flask pls.  note: code looks okay, once 404 resolved, need to add return statement in `login()` , for example `if len(name) != 0:
        return '<p>Data added Successfully</p>'
    else:
        return '<p>Error</p>'`